# Extract Excel items in time range to consecutive time

Tags: excel, excel-formula, time, range, excel-2007

Here’s a simple table with items in a time range.  The desired result table has all items mapped to their consecutive time slots.  What formula would you suggest accomplishing this task?  Thanks!

Original table:

| Item | Start | End |
| --- | --- | --- |
| BE | 8:00 AM | 8:02 AM |
| zeta | 8:06 AM | 8:24 AM |
| gamma | 8:13 AM | 9:02 AM |
| beta | 8:49 AM | 9:13 AM |
| BE | 8:56 AM | 8:58 AM |

Result table:

| Time | BE | zeta | gamma | beta |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8:00 AM | Y |  |  |  |
| 8:01 AM | Y |  |  |  |
| 8:02 AM | Y |  |  |  |
| 8:03 AM |  |  |  |  |
| 8:04 AM |  |  |  |  |
| 8:05 AM |  |  |  |  |
| 8:06 AM |  | Y |  |  |
| 8:07 AM |  | Y |  |  |
| 8:08 AM |  | Y |  |  |
| 8:09 AM |  | Y |  |  |
| 8:10 AM |  | Y |  |  |
| 8:11 AM |  | Y |  |  |
| 8:12 AM |  | Y |  |  |
| 8:13 AM |  | Y | Y |  |
| 8:14 AM |  | Y | Y |  |
| 8:15 AM |  | Y | Y |  |
| 8:16 AM |  | Y | Y |  |
| 8:17 AM |  | Y | Y |  |
| 8:18 AM |  | Y | Y |  |
| 8:19 AM |  | Y | Y |  |
| 8:20 AM |  | Y | Y |  |
| 8:21 AM |  | Y | Y |  |
| 8:22 AM |  | Y | Y |  |
| 8:23 AM |  | Y | Y |  |
| 8:24 AM |  | Y | Y |  |
| 8:25 AM |  |  | Y |  |
| 8:26 AM |  |  | Y |  |
| 8:27 AM |  |  | Y |  |
| 8:28 AM |  |  | Y |  |
| 8:29 AM |  |  | Y |  |
| 8:30 AM |  |  | Y |  |
| 8:31 AM |  |  | Y |  |
| 8:32 AM |  |  | Y |  |
| 8:33 AM |  |  | Y |  |
| 8:34 AM |  |  | Y |  |
| 8:35 AM |  |  | Y |  |
| 8:36 AM |  |  | Y |  |
| 8:37 AM |  |  | Y |  |
| 8:38 AM |  |  | Y |  |
| 8:39 AM |  |  | Y |  |
| 8:40 AM |  |  | Y |  |
| 8:41 AM |  |  | Y |  |
| 8:42 AM |  |  | Y |  |
| 8:43 AM |  |  | Y |  |
| 8:44 AM |  |  | Y |  |
| 8:45 AM |  |  | Y |  |
| 8:46 AM |  |  | Y |  |
| 8:47 AM |  |  | Y |  |
| 8:48 AM |  |  | Y |  |
| 8:49 AM |  |  | Y | Y |
| 8:50 AM |  |  | Y | Y |
| 8:51 AM |  |  | Y | Y |
| 8:52 AM |  |  | Y | Y |
| 8:53 AM |  |  | Y | Y |
| 8:54 AM |  |  | Y | Y |
| 8:55 AM |  |  | Y | Y |
| 8:56 AM | Y |  | Y | Y |
| 8:57 AM | Y |  | Y | Y |
| 8:58 AM | Y |  | Y | Y |
| 8:59 AM |  |  | Y | Y |
| 9:00 AM |  |  | Y | Y |
| 9:01 AM |  |  | Y | Y |
| 9:02 AM |  |  | Y | Y |
| 9:03 AM |  |  |  | Y |
| 9:04 AM |  |  |  | Y |
| 9:05 AM |  |  |  | Y |
| 9:06 AM |  |  |  | Y |
| 9:07 AM |  |  |  | Y |
| 9:08 AM |  |  |  | Y |
| 9:09 AM |  |  |  | Y |
| 9:10 AM |  |  |  | Y |
| 9:11 AM |  |  |  | Y |
| 9:12 AM |  |  |  | Y |
| 9:13 AM |  |  |  | Y |
| 9:14 AM |  |  |  |  |
| 9:15 AM |  |  |  |  |

Edit:

I just noticed that SUMPRODUCT() worked for most, but Beta is missing the first minute in the result table (8:49 AM).  File is here, https://u.pcloud.link/publink/show?code=XZDCONVZ6mQCoqWVEJB0W7AKyLTvNje9z3IX

Any ideas?

Comment: Is that a typo for `zeta`, i see all other seems to show `Y` from the correct start time while for only `zeta` instead of `08:06 AM` it starts from `08:05 AM` in the result table.

Comment: Yes, my bad, sorry for the typo.  Good catch!

Comment: I have updated your post, kindly use **[Markdown-Table-Generator](https://tabletomarkdown.com/convert-spreadsheet-to-markdown/)** for future posts, it helps to copy and paste the date in excel.

Comment: Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer. Compare https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using <kbd>XMATCH( )</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>F2</kbd>

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(XMATCH(1,($E2>=$B$2:$B$6)*($E2<=$C$2:$C$6)*(F$1=$A$2:$A$6))),"Y","")
```

---

Formula needs to fill down and fill right, also please try to change the cell references and ranges accordingly as per your suit.

---

You can also use a <kbd>BOOLEAN LOGIC</kbd> within a <kbd>SUM( )</kbd> function.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>F2</kbd>

```
=IF(SUM(($E2>=$B$2:$B$6)*($E2<=$C$2:$C$6)*(F$1=$A$2:$A$6)),"Y","")
```

---

Since OP is using **`Excel 2007`** hence replace the formula using <kbd>SUM( )</kbd> with <kbd>SUMPRODUCT( )</kbd> although the <kbd>SUM( )</kbd> would work but it would need to hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> while exiting the edit mode, also since you are not using the updated version, you can use <kbd>MATCH( )</kbd> function in place of <kbd>XMATCH( )</kbd> but using <kbd>SUMPRODUCT( )</kbd> will be faster than the rest.

---

Here is a screenshot where it shows it is not missing the first time `8:49 AM`  for Beta

[image]

---

### Edit 8/10/2023

Updated formula:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT((TIME(HOUR($E2),MINUTE($E2),)>=$B$2:$B$6)*
               (TIME(HOUR($E2),MINUTE($E2),)<=$C$2:$C$6)*
               (F$1=$A$2:$A$6)),"Y","")
```

---

[image]

---

Download the workbook from here: **[Workbook](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AlEkksoPTc2cjkjRMcXTwtYZYr9e?e=gwEWyW)**

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick answer.  Unfortunately, Excel 2007 does not have XMATCH.  Is there a workaround?

Comment: Then you can use either `MATCH()` function or `SUM()` or `SUMPRODUCT()` like i have updated using `SUM()`

Comment: with 2007 one will want to change the SUM() to SUMPRODUCT() or one will need to use Ctrl-Shift-Enter to array enter it.

Comment: @ScottCraner Sir, agree let me add the caveat, i didnt see the tags clearly because the post has so big screenshot i was lost in that

Comment: Also the `=1` is not necessarily needed, and may return false negatives if the times overlap for the same item.

Comment: @ScottCraner Sir, ah yes. let me check once and update it thanks

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya Thank you so much!  SUMPRODUCT() worked beautifully.  And thanks to Sir Scott Craner for the expert guidance. This will save me many hours of grunt work.

Comment: @Leo glad to know it worked for you, Yes thanks to Scott Craner Sir always.

Comment: Mayukh Bhattacharya, I just noticed that SUMPRODUCT() worked for most but Beta is missing the first minute in the result table (8:49 AM).  Any ideas?

Comment: Hi @Leo just check it is not missing , i will post a screenshot in the answers.

Comment: @Leo please check i have updated. It is certainly not missing

Comment: @Leo are you there, I found the problem, how did you enter those times?

Comment: @Mayukh Bhattacharya
Can you please open my file (link in edited post)? It shows the missing minute.

Comment: Yes, I have opened it , and found the problem, as you know date and time is stores as numbers in excel, hence it was showing too large fractions while mine is only 4 decimal places, I have updated the formula and post the excel also, please download it ok, also in your workbook it was not showing for `8:56 AM ` for BE

Comment: @Leo I have added the updated workbook, which should work for you, also you can download from here: **[Download](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AlEkksoPTc2cjkjRMcXTwtYZYr9e?e=gwEWyW)**

Comment: Once you find its ok, kindly update the post by removing the excel. So I will know its solved. or you can write in short as Solved., otherwise future members looking the question may think it was nt solved

Comment: @Leo glad to know it is working at your end at last. Nice =)